# Design dababase where every user has a list of favorites

Tags: mysql, database

I have a users database and a comments database on a website, and I want to give each user the ability to have a list of favorite comments, and I don't know exactly how to implement this.

Should I create a new table for each user containing the IDs of his/hers favorite comments or is there a better approach?

Comment: *"Should I create a new table for each user..."* - If you have 5-10 users; not bad. When it starts to be anything higher than that, you're looking at having to code for all of those different users with seperate table calls. You could create one table for your users and one for the favorites, then using a JOIN as a relation table. There are probably other ways to do this, but that's what comes to mind at this instant.

Comment: Your idea is also the first thing comes to my mind so it's one way to do it. You would end up with 1 to many relationships from `user` to `fav_comments` and 1 to many also with `fav_comments` to `comments` though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common, [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) approach would be a [many to many relationship](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561).

The schema for such a table, at a minimum, would be:

```
user_id
comment_id
```

Where `user_id` and `comment_id` are foreign keys to the `users` and `comments` table, respectively.

Comment: Wouldn't your solution mean that, for retrieving all the favorite comments for a user, you have to pass through the entire table of associations between a user and a comment? If the site has a lot of users and each user has at least 10 favorite comments, wouldn't that take a lot of time?

Comment: As noted, this is a normalized approach. Nonetheless, as this table only consists of keys such lookups should be performant. I would worry about such optimizations once you reach scale.

Comment: @Valdrinit If all tables are properly indexed, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use three tables :

1. The `users` table, containing every users, including their personal informations, etc ;
2. The `comments` table, containing every comments ;
3. The `favorites` table, containing the `id` of the row, the `id` of the user and the `id` of the comment.

I did not name each table well, you should think more about the tables' names (e.g: `favorites` is a bad name).